# How to make FlatList in Android bounce like in iOS?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve the bounciness of the FlatList in iOS and mimick it in my android version of the app. Currently if you keep scrolling when you reach the header or the footer of the list, the iOS FlatList will let you over scroll. It looks like this:

[image: iOS bounce]

However, on android the list just stops abruptly. How can I achieve the same effect on android? [This](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16144) issue is related but they havent found a fix neither. Any help is welcome!

Comment: this kind of overscroll behavior is not a thing on android, so I'd say you actually don't want to do it.

Comment: I know, I would still like to achieve it since I personally like it for the UX feel.